# Visualising $aw_1+bw_2=c \text{ where } a,b,c\in\mathbb R \quad w_1,w_2\in\mathbb C$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

$aw_1+bw_2=c \text{ where } a,b,c,w_1,w_2\in\mathbb R, $
Is wel known and well studied by pupils very early on
However I do not recall having seen $aw_1+bw_2=c \text{ where } a,b,c\in\mathbb R \quad w_1,w_2\in\mathbb C$ anywhere being considered worth a mention anywhere. 
Of course the solution would be set of points that their real parts and complex parts lie on some lines (independently).

My questions is, is there a way to visualise some how the solution set of point $w_1,w_2$ just as the case of simple line with the real variables?

Comment: $a(x+iy)+b(p+iq)=c$ or $ax+bp=c$ and $y+q=0$, if i am correctly interpreting what you are asking

Comment: @Shobhit : yes, but how is it visualised?

Comment: if c is real then the imaginary parts cancel out and it takes the form as is stated by you at the top of the question